# How to permanently delete enemy sprites in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I am new to XNA 4.0 and am trying to make a Super Mario Bros. type game where the player jumps down on the enemies to kill them. However I have run into a problem with killing the enemies. I have made a rectangle 15px below my character (`rectangleBox`) so that if it intersects with the enemy rectangle it will cause the `enemy.alive = false`. And if this `enemy.alive = false` it will not draw the enemy. However this only applies in the time when the rectangles intersect. Once the enemy leaves the bounds of the `rectangleBox` it appears again. How do I permanently delete the enemy so it will not respawn again until I have restarted the game?

Enemy class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace notDMIG
{
    class Enemy
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Rectangle bounds;
        public Vector2 position;
        public Vector2 velocity;
        public float timer = 0.0f;
        public int spriteNum = 1;
        public int maxSpriteNum;
        public bool alive;

        public Enemy(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position, Vector2 Velocity, int maxsprites)
        {
            texture = Texture;
            position = Position;
            velocity = Velocity;
            maxSpriteNum = maxsprites;
            alive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Game1.cs enemy related code

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
    {
        enemy.alive = true;

        Rectangle rectangleBox = new Rectangle((int)player.position.X, (int)player.position.Y + player.sprite.Height + 15, player.sprite.Width, 1);
        Rectangle enemyBox = new Rectangle((int)enemy.position.X, (int)enemy.position.Y, enemy.texture.Width, enemy.texture.Height);

        if (enemy.alive == true)
        {
            if (rectangleBox.Intersects(enemyBox))
            {
                enemy.alive = false;

                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
    {
        if (enemy.alive == true)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(enemy.texture, enemy.position, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having your enemy.alive = true in the Update method I'd recommend placing this in the initialize method instead. The initialize method is only called at the start of the program (where all enemies should be, technically, alive) while the update method is called hundreds of times a second. So what your program is doing is "Enemy intersects player, enemy is dead, next update loop, enemy is alive again".

So yeah I'd just place it in your initialize method instead of the Update.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I ended up setting alive = true in Enemy.cs and then not initializing it in Game1.cs butt his lead me in the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider not using your Alive property at all, and treat the objects that are in your List as enemies that are alive.  This in mind, I would refactor your code to the following:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Enemies.Count; i++)
    {
        //If player intersects enemy
        if ( player.Bounds.Intersects(Enemies[i].Bounds) )
        {
            Enemies.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
            continue;
        }               
    }
}


protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy.texture, enemy.position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

In my code, we now loop through each Enemy checking for an intersection.  If an intersection is found, we remove that enemy from the list.  This removes him forever, and greatly simplifies your code.

Typically when using a property such as .Alive, you would be using a Pool data structure.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your advice. I attempted this suggestion and did some further research on it but i ran into too many errors that just overwhelmed me. I will bring it up with my professor tomorrow however and see if i can be enlightened further.

Comment: I generally try to maintain a pool of enemy objects and reuse them rather than dispose them. If you make a game with a  lot of objects this can help prevent issues with the GC

Comment: But removing it from the list does not delete the enemy itself. Don't you have to call Dispose() or remove it from Game.Components?

Comment: @Kokodoko Leave the garbage collection to the garbage collector.  As long as your game no longer references the object, the gc will pick it up.  I also mentioned the use of a Pool data structure in my answer, for cases where you would prefer to re-use your memory space.

Comment: OK, so you never have to call enemy.Dispose() or Game.Components.Remove(enemy) ?

Comment: @Kokodoko You are using GameComponents for your enemies?  That is not a good design.  GameComponents should be used sparingly, for certain things, such as an FPS counter for example.  In short, just don't use GameComponents, I remember even reading that MS staff was saying that they were flawed by design and should of been deprecated.

Comment: @Kokodoko See here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-are-the-cons-of-using-drawablegamecomponent-for-every-instance-of-a-game-ob

Comment: Thanks :) I do find the DrawableGameComponent quite handy to use! So without DGC you only have to remove a reference from your list/pool to completely remove the element from memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74211/discussion-between-jon-and-kokodoko).